# Update database without changing its values(add new rows in a table)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When every time I update my app, the database always changes back to zero, and all of my previous progressions are all gone. I just added a new table, and added a few rows. I saw in the corona forums that I should use the Documents Directory so the database will not be updated. But when I do that, my app gets messed up, so I still used the  systems Resource Directory, any tips on how should I use my database?

```
local path = system.pathForFile("database/inventorydb.db",system.ResourceDirectory)
db = sqlite3.open(path)


            db:exec([[UPDATE tbl]].. selectedStageH1 ..[[ SET count = ']]..yogurtNumber..[[' WHERE type = 'yogurt']])
            db:exec([[UPDATE tbl]].. selectedStageH1 ..[[ SET count = ']]..waffleNumber..[[' WHERE type = 'waffle']])
            db:exec([[UPDATE tbl]].. selectedStageH1 ..[[ SET count = ']]..smoothieNumber..[[' WHERE type = 'smoothie']])
            db:exec([[UPDATE tbl]].. selectedStageH1 ..[[ SET count = ']]..coffeeNumber..[[' WHERE type = 'coffee']])
            db:exec([[UPDATE money SET pera = ']]..moneyAddition..[[' WHERE id = '1']])
            if realRating >= 1 then
                nextLevel = lvlNumber + 1
                db:exec([[UPDATE levels SET status = 'done' WHERE level = ']]..nextLevel..[[']])
            end
            if realRating >= currentRating then
                db:exec([[UPDATE ratingdb SET stars = ']]..realRating..[[' WHERE level = ']]..lvlNumber..[[']])
            end
            local options = {

                    effect = "fade", time = 500, params = { selectedStage = selectedStageH1,}
                            }
```

so basically this all simple I provided the connection string plus the code that updates the levelstate and level rating, so when every time i reinstall the app on my device, whatever is in the resource directory will be saved on the device, thus overwriting the database in the device.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot write to the ResourceDirectory (you may in simulator but not in device). You have to do it in the DocumentsDirectory. I do not know what do you get messed up when doing so, but that should be the place. I have a couple of apps working that way and have no problem.

The Resource directory is that, the resource. So everytime you reload the app it will use that resources you have there from the beginning. The working directories are both the Documents, Temporary and Cache depending on the use.

Comment: I think what makes my DocumentsDirectory on Mobile Device(upon first installation) its because it is absent. That's why my app gets messed upped because it can no longer find the tables in my database